# Why is my external webcam listed multiple times and how can I tidy it up?

Tags: macos, mojave, webcam

I have a Logitech C920 HD webcam plugged into my MacMini 2012. I've just moved it into a different USB port and now it shows up twice  (only one is available) in camera selection e.g. Logitech C920 HD #2 appears.

I would like to remove these 'ghost' devices, how can I do this?

Comment: Have you restarted?

Comment: The new one is still called '#2' even if the original one is missing

Comment: I'll take that as Yes. ;-) It's likely that the info is held in a .plist file somewhere. Use an app like EasyFind to search for the camera's name in the whole disk; or check what files were modified when they change.